# Which is the latest stable prawn (pdf generation) version?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

Which is the latest stable prawn (pdf generation) version ?
does it support prawn-format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) easy and effective.

Comment: yea i liked it. its more easy than prawn.

Answer (score 3):

See the [official GitHub repository of Prawn](https://github.com/sandal/prawn) for the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

prawn 1.0.0.rc1 is latest version and its not stable version yet. but seems its much better than prawn 0.12.0

BUT alternative and best generator for ROR is [wicked pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) for full comparable you have to install [patched version of QT](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)